# Dependency Resolution error

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, kite-sdk

I am trying to convert JSON file to Parquet format using Kites SDK.

I have the following pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>JSONToParquet</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kitesdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>kite-data-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kitesdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>kite-morphlines-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version> <!-- or whatever the latest version is -->
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ua_parser/ua-parser -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ua_parser</groupId>
            <artifactId>ua-parser</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>


</project>
```

But When I try to Build my project. I am getting the following error :

```
The POM for ua_parser:ua-parser:jar:1.3.0 is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for ua_parser:ua-parser:pom:1.3.0 is missing, no dependency information available
```

I am not able to understand the root cause of this issue.

Comment: without the full pom file its hard to guess for others as well...

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Can you check if the `.m2` folder is having `settings.xml`?

Comment: Nope I am not behind a proxy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ua_parser`is not available via [Maven central](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/), but via the [wso2 repository](http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/). By adding

```xml
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>wso2</id>
    <url>http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

to your pom, you are able to access the artifacts in the wso2 repository.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `com.github.ua-parser` which is present in maven central

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ua-parser</groupId>
    <artifactId>uap-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.ua-parser/uap-java